# Symfony 4 API Platform and JWT : how to login on API with a Symfony client project?

Tags: api, symfony, client, jwt, guzzle

I'm working on a Symfony 4 API Platform project and have a Symfony 4 client project with who I want to login on the API. I'm using guzzle for accessing resources on the API.

Here is for example `GuzzleTrait` that I've implemented :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: simslay
 * Date: 15/12/2018
 * Time: 15:29
 */

namespace App\Controller;


use GuzzleHttp\Client;

trait GuzzleTrait
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8001'
        ]);
    }

    private function getContent(string $finUri) {
        $content = null;

        try {
            $dataContent = $this->client->request('GET', 'api/'.$finUri);
            $content = json_decode($dataContent->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException $e) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'danger',
                $e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

I'm working on this tutorial : [Implementing JWT Authentication to your API Platform application](https://emirkarsiyakali.com/implementing-jwt-authentication-to-your-api-platform-application-885f014d3358)

and have the same logic on my API.

Also, here is my client security.yaml :

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: surnom
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

            form_login:
                login_path: security_connexion
                check_path: security_connexion
                username_parameter: _surnom
                password_parameter: _password
                default_target_path: index
            provider: user_provider
            logout:
                path: /deconnexion
                target: /

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

I have a database on the API with a User entity.

Is it necessery to have also a User entity on client side ?

In curl, for login I have the command :

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'`

How to login from the Symfony 4 client to the API ?

Comment: You need infact to have a valide JWT token that you gonna use it as a key that let you authenticate, you need to configure your api firewall and the guard sectionas it's mentionned in the tuto. You can work with any jwt php beblio.  you dont have to have  a User entity on client side  but it's recommanded to create a javascript dto where you can bind you data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand a bit what you say. But where do I have to code my request `http://localhost:8000/login_check` in client side ? Maybe in a controller action for login ? Do you have some code example ?

Comment: hmm noarmally you build an API so you probably you a client side to consume an apy where you ganna call the login_check bah voila

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement client authentication following this [code example](https://github.com/nielsvandermolen/example_symfony4_api) from this [tutorial:](https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/symfony-4-api-platform-application/) .